# Add single multiindex column values

Tags: python, pandas

In attached dataframe I want to sum of all the values under the "count" column and store in a new column say "CC", i.e.:

```
df['CC'] = [620,764]
```

I want to perform this with only single column. I tried following but no luck.

```
df['count'].sum(level=0,axis=1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSEvI.png)

Comment: Please do not paste images of your data, but include them in text format in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `print(df.columns)` to see the column name. To perform sum on a single column, you can do

```py
df[('count', 'batch')].sum()
```

If you want to assign sum value to a new column

```py
df['CC'] = df[('count', 'batch')].agg('sum')

# or

df['CC'] = df[('count', 'batch')].sum()
```